# Foundation 5 top bar - disable default behaviour in mobile view for right hand links

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I need help customising foundations top-bar menu.  I have a pretty standard top bar set up with a left hand menu and a right hand menu.

The default foundation behaviour on a mobile is for both right and left menus to be combined as a single drop down with a menu icon the right hand side.

I want to change this behaviour somehow so that the right and left hand menus are separate.  I would want the left hand menu to use the default behaviour but I would need the menu icon to be moved to the left. I want to disable the default behaviour for the right hand menu so that these remain the same on all screen sizes.  Below is an image of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Anyone got any idea where I would start with this?

```
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar >
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title Area -->
            <li class="name">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- main nav section -->
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Links</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Dropdown Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--Language, account, currency section-->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="account">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour1"><i class="fi-en"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Languages</a></li></ul> 
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="basket">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour2"><i class="fi-dollar"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Currency</a></li></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="currency">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour3"><i class="fi-lock medium"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Login</a></li></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
```

Many thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to change this behaviour somehow so that the right and left hand menus are separate` ? i need to understand this to be able to help you. can you draw the end result or be clear?

Comment: well the default behaviour is that both left and right hand menus are merged and become one menu on a mobile.  I want them to remain  separate so that the left hand menu is displayed when the menu icon is selected and the right hand menu remains the same on mobile as it does on full screen.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: Ok the last update is in the answer now it is up to you and `media query`

Answer (score 1):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjscsmL6/17/)

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
            <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small">

            <section class="top-bar-section">                        <!-- main nav section Left Nav Section--> 
                    <ul class="left">
                        <div class="right small-6">
                            <ul class="row">
                                <li class="has-dropdown not-click small-4 columns" id="account">
                                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour1"><i class="fi-en">icon</i></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Languages</a></li> 
                                    </ul> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown not-click small-4 columns" id="basket">
                                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour2"><i class="fi-dollar">icon</i></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown not-click">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Currency</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown not-click small-4 columns" id="currency">
                                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour3"><i class="fi-lock medium">icon</i></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li  class="active"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
                            <span></span>
                        </a>
                    </ul>   
                </section>
        </nav>
```

```
        <div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
            <nav class="top-bar hide-for-small" data-topbar>
                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <ul class="title-area left">
                        <li class="name hide-for-small">
                            <a></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- main nav section Left Nav Section-->
                    <ul class="left">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
                            <a href="#">Links</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                        <!--Language, account, currency section Right Nav Section-->
                    <ul class="right">
                        <li class="has-dropdown not-click" id="account">
                            <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour1"><i class="fi-en">icon</i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Languages</a></li> 
                            </ul> 
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-dropdown not-click" id="basket">
                            <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour2"><i class="fi-dollar">icon</i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown not-click">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Currency</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-dropdown not-click" id="currency">
                            <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour3"><i class="fi-lock medium">icon</i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li  class="active"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </nav>
        </div> <a class="exit-off-canvas" href="#"></a>
        <article class="small-12 columns">
            <main>
            </main>
        </article>
        <footer class="small-12 columns">

        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Is this incomplete it doesn't seem to work in your demo?  Sorry I don't understand exactly what I need to do to get this working.  I have noticed you have swtiched the markup so that the icons are first, but this doesn't appear to make any difference.  Please confirm.

Comment: Not this is just the first step make a fiddle with you code and you will see the difference. By the way switching the markup has nothing to do with the solution. Now i need to now what the end result shall look like, maybe a draw can help. note that you will have to deal with  foundation classes and media query `large-12 medium-uncentered medium-push-5 small-centered small-pull-6 columns`. This is how your demo looks like http://jsfiddle.net/jff4wbeg/

Comment: I dont see any difference so I don't really see the point, sorry.  I need a solution to have the menu look like the above example on mobile

Comment: ok i was just trying to make you understand how it work and not just give you the final result. But if that is what you want i am updating the answer

Comment: I want the 3 icons on the right hand side to stay visible regardless of the screen size.  I also want the menu icon to be on the left hand side when on mobile as shown in the example above.  Hope that clarifies things for you.

Comment: Just realised that this isn't what I was looking for at all. I have been very busy on anotehr project and have only just come back to this to realise that its not correct. Has this been changed?

Comment: The dropdown on the left is now an off canvas menu, thats is not what I wanted.  Also the right hand menu doesn't dropdown on a small screen.  I need the right hand side to stay the same regardless of size.  I awarded the bounty in haste :(

Comment: If you don't need the  canvas menu just build a new menu as you want it to be  on small screen.

Comment: So have two sets of code for basically the same menu?  I thought the whole  point of using foundation was sp that I wouldn't have two sets of code :/

Comment: No you can do that too but that with the canvas was just an example how you can solve it. if you wan the same menu just use foundation regular classes for small screens

Comment: OK, its confusing for me as your demo doesn't do what I wanted and it has changed multiple times. I originally tried using foundations classes but couldn't solve it, hence putting it on here. I'll re-post this and see if anyone else can figure it out.

Comment: In fact, I may just have to go with the off canvas solution, but how do I get the right hand icons to still drop down on small?